# Wordpress Plugin WP-Ratings

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Всем добрый день, помогите разобраться, можно ли сделать на этом плагине поиск по рейтингу? Знаю, что можно сделать вывод по популярным и самым низким рейтингом, для этого следует поменять функцию `get_highest_rated` на `get_lowest_rated`. Либо же самых оцениваемых постов `get_most_rated`.

```
 <?php if (function_exists('get_highest_rated')): ?>
 <ul>
 <?php get_highest_rated('both', 0, 10); ?>
 </ul>
 <?phpendif; ?>
```

Как усовершенствовать этот код, чтобы, к примеру, выводило посты не выше 1 рейтинга?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрел код плагина. Файл \wp-postratings\includes\postratings-stats.php содержит 18 функций для вывода различной статистики, вроде get_highest_rated(). Того, что вам нужно, там нет.

Так что с помощью плагина сделать этого нельзя, надо разбирать какую-то функцию, например, get_highest_rated() и модифицировать ее для получения желаемого результата.

Comment: в админ панеле есть возможность поиск по рейтингу. Можно как-то вытянуть эти данные и прикрутить к сайту?
Примерно такое выводит при фильтрации:
postratings-manager.php&id=0&user&rating=4&by=date&order=asc&perpage=20

Comment: Просто так эти функции в админке, не вызвать в своем коде. Надо их изучать и делать свои подобные.